# Disallowed Key Characters error when moving EE website to another server

Tags: codeigniter, cookies

I want to move an EE 4.3.5 website from a development server to a production server. In this purpose, I have applied the steps presented [here](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/operations/moving.html) in the EE documentation.

But, when I want to access the Control Panel on the production server, the browser displays a Disallowed Key Characters error.

I have applied the the first answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40469280/it-shows-disallowed-key-characters-in-chrome-for-all-codeigniter-project) to have more info about the error. At line 997 of system/ee/legacy/core/input.php, I have added the $str variable into the $error variable.

Now, the browser shows : **Disallowed Key Characters exp_last_visit**

It appears that the error comes frome the exp_last_visit value, which seems to be a cookie.

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens when there is a clash between the cookies.
Give clearing your browser cookies, or at least delete the EE ones a try.
A good way to thwart this is to set a unique cookie prefix/domain for the site/server.
you can find the cookie overrides here: https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/general/system_configuration_overrides.html  I's start with cookie_domain and cookie_prefix

Comment: Please see my answer above. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Jim, but that did not solve the problem.

I have created another test domain to try what your suggested and moved my website to it. I have added the cookie_domain and cookie_prefix overrides in the config.php file but the "Disallowed Key Characters" error still displays.

Fortunately, my production website is OK. Yesterday, I copied and pasted the files from dev to prod directory with Plesk, instead of downloading then reuploading by FTP. With this method, I don't have the error. But I just can't explain why.

Anyway, I will report a bug. Moving a website from a directory/server to another should not generate this kind of issue. I have worked on several websites under EE2 and that never happened. This is my first EE4 and I am very badly surprise to meet such an issue.